# WordPress form two queries on one submission

Tags: javascript, mysql, wordpress, forms, submit

I made a form with such a code:

```
    <form name="wyszukiwarka" id="wyszukiwarka" class="wyszukiwarka" >
        <select class="miasto" id="pa_miasto" name="pa_miasto">
            <option class='opcja' value='miastoValue'>MiastoValue</option>
            ....      
        </select>
        <select class="typ-ogloszenia" id="product_cat" name="product_cat" required >     
            <option class='opcja' value='ProductCatValue'>TypValue</option>
            .....
        </select>

        <input type="submit" value = "Szukaj" >
    </form>
```

What I want it to do is:

1. User chooses value from `pa_miasto` and `product_cat`
2. User submits form
3. User gets query like this: `mysite.com/category/ProductCatValue/?pa_miasto=miastoValue`

I'm using GET method right now and it's working like this:

- When I choose only one select and submit, it goes right into the proper category without any database '?' query in URL;

> Example: mysite.com/category/ProductCatValue

- When I choose both selects and submit, it doesn't go to any category, it just searches database with '?' query using both parameters (`pa_miasto` and `product_cat`);

> Example: mysite.com/?product_cat=ProductCatValue&pa_miasto=miastoValue

So the thing I want to achieve is a bit like halfway between these two actions.

My question is: Is it some kind WordPress function that redirects to proper category while getting fitting argument keys or is it something else?

The second question is: Can I somehow split this query into two on one submission to get the result I want? (for example, using some Javascript function).

I hope it's clear. I just want to reduce the amount of options in the further filtering. I can provide site URL if there would be some problems with understanding.